# How to Qubes CD boot?

Tags: qubes

My laptops USB port are totally busted. I'm trying to make a Qubes boot disc (4.7Gb DVD+RW) using Debian. I've already tried `xfburn` with default settings which didn't work. (I've had success with xfburn+debian ISOs before).

The laptop is fairly new, purchased 3yrs ago for $1100, Sony.

I couldn't find any documentation on the qubes site about creating DVDRW mediums for qubes.

http://qubesosmamapaxpa.onion/doc/installation-guide/

Rather than frustrate myself, I'm hoping someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Qubes seems...tangential to Tor? Also it has (very) limited hardware support. It's possible that it simply won't work with your laptop (see the Qubes website for details)

Answer (score 1):

Qubes-R3.2-x86_64.iso is equipped with an El Torito boot record and
boot images for BIOS and UEFI. So it should boot from DVD if burned as
image without any further data manipulation. If it then shows messages 
of SYSLINU/ISOLINUX or GRUB, then booting has succeeded as far as
the DVD boot equipment is concerned. (It may then well fail because
the operating system in the ISO is not suitable for the machine.)